# How to use Charles to intercept requests from android phone?

Tags: android, charles-proxy

I'm using Android 10 phone, not using an emulator. I'm following [this tutorial](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Tealium-for-Android/Setting-up-Charles-to-Proxy-your-Android-Device/ta-p/5121),

Using Charles on windows 10 (Wireless Network), set android phone proxy with windows ip address.

Android Phone:

```
IP: 192.168.0.155/24 
GWT 192.168.0.1
PROXY: 192.168.0.133 
PORT: 8888
```

Windows 10:

```
IP: 192.168.0.133/24
GTW: 192.168.0.1.
```

But on Charles does not show up the pop up for accepting the new connection. Even following this tutorial, I'm not being able to make this work.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Did you follow the additional configuration steps for Android N (7.0) and up: https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Tealium-for-Android/Setting-up-Charles-to-Proxy-your-Android-Device/ta-p/5121#toc-hId-735733144

Comment: yeap! The app that I want debug when I built the apk, already insertted these Additional Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a third-party DNS server for your Windows machine's network interface, such as Cloudflare (1.1.1.1).